# Why can't you execute a bash command with temporary env variable assignment?

Tags: bash

More concisely in code -- why does this work:

`X=5 eval "echo \$X"`

outputs: `5`

But not this:

```
substitute_cmd='X=5 eval "echo \$X"'
$substitute_cmd
```

outputs: `-bash: X=5: command not found`

& Are there any good workarounds for it?

Comment: Not sure why you want to do such thing but this link might help, [Complex](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: Because assignments (at the beginning) and redirections (anywhere) are recognized and 'saved' _before_ the rest of the command is processed for parameter/variable expansions, so the result of an expansion will not be recognized as an assignment or redirection (except inside something that re-parses, like eval or parallel or an explicit new shell). Using instead an alias or function (invoked _without_ dollarsign) works, but I offer no opinion whether those are good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `eval`: it has a built-in interprets, which means it behaves as the same way when you type the command in the shell.
- `$cmd`: it will expand the variable, and literally treats the cmd here as a executable command

Here, `X=5` is not a executable command, it needs a shell to interprets it, so `eval` ok for you, while `$cmd` not ok for you. You still need another `eval` outside to help you like next:

```
$ substitute_cmd='X=5 eval "echo \$X"'
$ eval $substitute_cmd
5
```